# PHP DateInterval format minutes and seconds with leading zero

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

Trying to generate simple "H:i:s" string from seconds, but can't

example:

```
$iSecond = 188;
$dtF = new DateTime("@0");
$dtT = new DateTime("@$iSecond");
$size = $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%H:%i:%s');
echo $size;
```

should show "00:03:08" , but in fact "00:3:8"

if there is some another date format options to use in format method?

there is fiddle https://3v4l.org/Coi7q

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use capital `I` and `S` for your formatting:

```
$size = $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

See [the manual for all of the formatting options](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

[Demo](https://eval.in/438968)

Comment: yep, works perfect, just didn't realized that DateTime format is different from date() function

Comment: They're usually the same but they have a few gotchas to keep you on your toes. :)

Comment: @user5267736, the DateTime format is the same, but when you use diff(), you're returning a DateInterval object, not a DateTime object.

Answer (score 4):

John is correct, but your code seems unnecessary, this should be the same:

```
$iSecond = 188;
$dtT = new DateTime("@$iSecond");
$size = $dtT->format('H:i:s');
```

There is no reason to create a datetime of @0 and use diff/DateInterval in this code.